# Retuning values from HTTP POST instead of Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm working on a city based angular application.

1. getPlaceId function will get the google `place_id` value.
2. Based on the `place_id` `getPlacesPhotoRef` should return 10 photo ref.

What I'm trying to do is, I wanted the `photo ref` to be pushed to photo's array.

expected output.

```
{
 formatted_address: 'xxx',
 place_id: 'xxx',
 photos: [...] //All 10 photo ref
}
```

But issue is, instead of values, I see Observable getting returned in the photos array.

Below is my code

```
  getPlaceId(cityName) {
    let httpPath = `http://localhost:5001/calvincareemailservice/us-central1/webApi/api/v1/getplaces`;
    return this.http.post(httpPath, { city: cityName }).subscribe(res => {
      if (res) {
        let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
        this.placeIds.push({
          formatted_address: data.candidates[0].formatted_address, 
          place_id: data.candidates[0].place_id, 
          photos: this.getPlacesPhotoRef(data.candidates[0].place_id)
          .subscribe(res => {
            let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
            return data.result.photos.map(pic => pic.photo_reference);
          })
        }
        );
      }
    });
  }

  getPlacesPhotoRef(id) {
    let httpPath = `http://localhost:5001/calvincareemailservice/us-central1/webApi/api/v1/getplacesid`;
    return this.http.post(httpPath, { placeId: id })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close and thinking about the problem correctly, but the issue is you have assigned an Observable subscription to your `photos` key rather than the data the `.subscribe()` actually returned, which I would imagine is what you had hoped you were doing.

At a high level, what you want to do is push a new object to `this.placeIds` once you have all of the information it needs, e.g. `formatted_address`, `place_id` and `photos`. So what you need to do here is:

1. Call the `/getplaces` endpoint and store the place data
2. Call the `/getplacesid` endpoint using `data.candidates[0].place_id` and store the photos data
3. After **both** endpoints have returned construct an object using all the data and push this object to `this.placeIds`

Simple example with nested `.subscribe()` calls:

```
getPlaceId(cityName) {
    const httpPath = `http://localhost:5001/calvincareemailservice/us-central1/webApi/api/v1/getplaces`;

    return this.http.post(httpPath, { city: cityName })
      .subscribe(res => {
        if (res) {
          const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
          const formatted_address = data.candidates[0].formatted_address;
          const place_id = data.candidates[0].place_id
        
          this.getPlacesPhotoRef(place_id)
            .subscribe(res => {
              const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
              const photos = data.result.photos.map(pic => pic.photo_reference)
            
              this.placeIds.push({
                formatted_address,
                place_id,
                photos
              })
            })
          );
        }
    });
  }
```

Note: A more elegant way to do this would be to use [`concatMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap)